# Does DocumentDB support the LIKE keyword in queries?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Can we use the `LIKE` keyword to filter out records as we use it in T-SQL?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The keyword for `LIKE` is `CONTAINS`. If you had a document with a `firstName` property and you wanted to filter on the name `'bob'` you would use it in a query this way:

`"SELECT * FROM c WHERE CONTAINS(c.firstName, 'bob')"`

Or if you were using `Linq` and assuming you had a class `Person` with a `FirstName` property the same query would work this way:

```
 var dbClient = GetClient();
 var docs = dbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Person>(Collection)
                    .Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains("bob");
```

Comment: Agree with the comment above. If you'd like to see LIKE added in the DocumentDB query grammar, please up-vote here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6333414-implement-wildcards-when-searching

Comment: A couple more `%`-like options from Aravind's link: "*Azure Cosmos DB supports the CONTAINS, **STARTSWITH, and ENDSWITH** built-in functions which are equivalent to LIKE.*" (emph mine, natch)